# How can I get the current ReactContext in MainActivity's onCreate function?

Tags: android, react-native

I need to call a native module in `MainActivity`'s onCreate function by: `context.getNativeModule(RNBackgroundToForegroundServiceModule.class)`

But I am not sure how to get the current `ReactContext` there.

I tried to use `(ReactContext) getApplicationContext()` but it crashes.

How can I get the valid `ReactContext`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came up with the right answer myself.
We have to wait until the Javascript bundle is loaded.

```js
ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
        ReactApplicationContext context = (ReactApplicationContext) mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
        mReactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
            public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext validContext) {
                // Use validContext here
               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this in your ReactActivity:

```
getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
```

Just make sure you implemented **ReactApplication** in your Application class.

**IMPORTANT:**
It takes time for the ReactContext to be available because there is the UI thread and the JS thread, so in 'onCreate' you can use a Handler with delay of 1 sec for example, the ReactContext should be available:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ReactContext reactContext = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

But I recommend you do your stuff from a ReactContextBaseJavaModule where the context is provided on creation...

Comment: It is null in `onCreate`.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: In a module that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`, I'm unable to receive the `ACTION_SEND` intent, it always gets `VIEW`. How can I get the `ACTION_SEND` instead?

Comment: did you add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />` in the `<intent-filter>` of your `Activity` in the `Manifest`?

Comment: @HedeH Yes I did add that

Answer (score -1):

it's work for me with answer 4

```
 mReactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
        public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext validContext) {
            // Use validContext here
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            sendEvent(validContext, "appStateChange", params);
        }
    });
```